# Sharepoint list meta data and query all the meta data for the list item using REST

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, rest, metadata

I am trying to programmatically download the sharepoint lists and list item content using REST api.

Here is the approach I am taking.

1. Get all the lists in sharepoint using lists end point

   _api/web/lists
2. For each list item found, get all the meta data using

   _api/Web/Lists(guid'3e193bc5-eff6-432a-b5d2-06cdc2619975')/Fields

The problem I am running into is that there are some fields  such as FileSystemObjectType that are missing in the response from '/Fields'

The other issue I have is that all the fields that show up in the response from '/Fields' do not show up when I query the list item as follows:

```
_api/Web/Lists(guid'3e193bc5-eff6-432a-b5d2-06cdc2619975')/Items
```

I would like to know how I can get all the meta data about the list items (fields names and types including if the item is file or folder) and how to query for the list item for all the fields.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to msdn you can use `[$select=* t][1]` query, which should return all the fields that are available

Comment: This still doesnt give all the fields. Thanks for the pointer though.